# Условие неразрешимости задачи линейного программирования

Tags: математика

Допустим, есть такая задача :

```
F(x) = x1 + x2 + x3 -> max
{            x1 + x2 + x3 <=  2
{                      x1 >=  1
{ -2 * x1 -2 * x2 -2 * x3 <= -10
{              x1, x2, x3 >= 0
```

Ясно, что такая система не имеет решения.

Есть ли какие-то эффективные способы вычислять "нерешаемость" таких систем сразу? Т.е. не строить, например, симплекс таблицу и не определять их нерешаемость уже посредством симплекс таблицы.

Comment: Ну, если сама постановка задачи указывает, что решения нет, то понятно, что какие бы эквивалентные преобразования вы не применяли, решения найдено не будет.

Comment: Возможно, что уже вечер и я ничего не соображаю, но вопрос типа "является ли масло масляным", ибо если уравнения границ определяют пустое множество, то этого достаточно, чтобы задача оптимизации на этом множестве не имела решения

Comment: Любые дополнительные достаточные условия могут лишь уменьшить множество возможных решений. Но если из-за неразрешимости системы это множество уже является пустым, то уменьшать его просто некуда.

Answer (score 0):

Если условия задачи противоречивы (а ограничения - это просто часть условий), то задача не имеет решения, что с ней не делай.